# How to migrate the local database on heroku with new tables?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I get the error:

```
Exception Value:    
no such table: hello_surname
```

when i try to show a view that accesses the Surname model

in my models.py

```
class Surname(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
```

I've tried to run the migrate `$ heroku run python manage.py migrate`

ouput:

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ sleepy-fjord... up, run.7027

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, auth, hello, contenttypes, admin
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

then i run `$ heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`

output:

```
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ sleepy-fjord... up, run.8567
Migrations for 'hello':
  0002_surname.py:
    - Create model Surname
```

when i run the top migrate again, it just gives the same output as when i ran it the first time. Seems like I am missing a step here, but with the output i can't seem to figure it out by myself. Anyone know any solutions?

Comment: ./manage.py makemigrations myappname

Comment: So you mean to say that when you do `$ heroku run python manage.py migrate` after `$ heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`, you still get **No migrations to apply** as well as **Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.** ?? Or just the **No migrations to apply** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** run make migrations *locally*, commit the results, then run migrate on Heroku.

Comment: Sorry i am a little bit new to the concept, how would you specifically run it locally?

Comment: If i'm not wrong then, what @Daniel means to say is that you need to simply `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` on your local and not heroku. Then you need to commit on heroku i.e., `git push heroku master` and then run migrate on heroku. I'm i right Daniel or did I miss anything?